# Dart dynamic class type

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

I have an abstract class "MyItem" and two classes that extend it, "Item1" and "Item2".

The class "MyItem" is defined `MyItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);` and both that extend it implement the function `fromMap`.

I'm trying to create a function as follows:

```
  Future<T> getById<T extends MyItem>(String table, int id) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> item = getItemAsMap(table, id);
    return T.fromMap(item);
  }
```

But the IDE (VSCode) tells me that I have an error:

```
The method 'fromMap' isn't defined for the type 'Type'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'fromMap'.
```

Any insight on what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT** Here is the code for the classes:

```
abstract class MyItem {
  MyItem({
    @required this.name,
  });
  String name;

  MyItem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map);
}

class Item1 extends MyItem {
  Item1({
    this.name,
  }) : super(name: name);
  String name;

  @override
  Item1.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    name = "item 1 name is: ${map['name']}";
  }
}

class Item2 extends MyItem {
  Item2({
    this.name,
    this.address,
  }) : super(name: name);
  String name;
  String address;

  @override
  Item1.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    name = "item 2 name is: ${map['name']}";
    address = map['address'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Does your abstract class define this method for implementation? Please show us your class's code

Comment: @casraf sorry for not adding the code in the first place. yes it implements it, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart does not allow generic constructors. `T` is a generic type. Consider using of `factory` constructors.

```dart
class MyItem {
  factory MyItem(Type type, Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    if (type == Item1) {
      return Item1.fromMap(map);
    } else if (type == Item2) {
      return Item2.fromMap(map);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is unfortunate, thank you for the answer.

Comment: As variant you may try to use `get_it` package which implements service locator. Then use it to instantiate objects like `return locator.getIt<T>().fromMap(map)`.